# Create Database Scoped Credential using variables for username (Identity) and password (Secret)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure on an Azure SQL server that is involved in the cleanup process after copying databases to another environment. In the SP I have something like

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyCredential
    WITH IDENTITY = 'SomeUsername',
    SECRET = 'SomePassword'
```

I don't want to store these credentials inside the SP so I thought it would be smart to do it like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_someTask](@username nvarchar(20),@password nvarchar(50))
AS
[...]
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyCredential
    WITH IDENTITY = @username,
    SECRET = @password
[...]
```

and provide the credentials in an external script that is calling the SP. But now I get an error

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '@username'.

Any suggestions on how I can use dynamic credentials here?

Comment: The statement does not allow variables for either the user name or the secret, so you'll have to get creative with dynamic SQL, taking care to escape single quotes.

Comment: Side note as well, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure your quotations are necessary around your secret and everything must fit on a single line or be joined by +**

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_someTask1]
(@username nvarchar(20),
@password nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @command varchar(MAX)

SET @command =     
'CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyCredential ' +
'WITH IDENTITY = '''+ @username + '''' + 
',SECRET = '''+ @password + ''''
EXECUTE (@command);

PRINT 'Database Scoped Credential Created'

END
```

for execution and checking execution completed or not

```sql
EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_someTask1] 'user','123456789';

select * from sys.database_scoped_credentials
```

***OUTPUT***
Scoped Credentials are created successfully.

[image]

Comment: Try `'This is a ''valid password'''` for the input to see it blow up.

Comment: Or alternatively, try passing the value `N'My password ∆¶✓'` for the password and then try logging in with that password.